# Having problems to show barcode in pdf with Apache Cocoon

Tags: xslt, pdf-generation, barcode, xsl-fo, apache-cocoon

I'm working with Apache Cocoon. I'm trying to "print" a barcode in pdf but it is not working. I'm using the `C39HrP24DhTt.TTF` font to do it. When the file's output format is `HTML` it shows the codebar correctly, but when the output format is `PDF`, it shows the text `Bar Code Here`.

Here is the relevant portion of my code in the `.xsl` file:

```
<fo:table-cell display-align="center" number-columns-spanned="2">
   <fo:block font-size="11pt" font-family="C39HrP24DhTt" font-weight="bold" color="#333333" text-align="right" padding-top="0.2cm">
         Bar Code Here
   </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Comment: Any warnings you have encountered? E.g. the font "C39HrP24DhTt" being substituted for something else?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code snippet you have shown (except that the font "C39HrP24DhTt" might not be available to the FO processor, but that does not make sense if this problem does not arise when outputting HTML). Please show more XSL-FO code, the HTML output and also explain the changes to Cocoon to generate PDF instead of HTML.